# Bootstrap navbar problems on iOS

Tags: ios, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm working on a personal website, and my Navigation Bar is coming up just fine on my laptop, but it's having some issues on iOS. On OS X, the NavBar shows each `< li >` as a separate button, but on iOS the navbar shows the "navbar-brand" button on the left and then a button which seems to be a dropdown menu on the right.

I assumed this button was because of the collapsed view, and would therefore bring up my buttons in a dropdown menu. Unfortunately, this is just a dead button, and nothing comes up when pressed, so I have no way of accessing the original buttons.

Here's the navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Braden Katzman</a>
  </div>

  <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="/templates/education.html">Education</a></li>
      <li><a href="/templates/workExperience.html">Work Experience</a></li>
      <li><a href="/templates/csSkills.html">CS Skills</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
</div>
```

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance!

Comment: That code seems to work fine for me. Have you remembered to link the Bootstrap CSS, JS and JQuery? Remember you need to include the link to JQuery before Bootstrap's JS.

Comment: That was it! Needed to switch the order of the linked files. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad I could help! I've posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I can't see any errors with your code.

Have you included JQuery, the Bootstrap JS and Bootstrap CSS? Remember that JQuery needs to be included before the Bootstrap JS.

Comment: Hi @BrandenKatzman if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.